# Guess the error in the insert statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, insert, connection-string

Anybody out there with some eagle eyes? I want to fish out the location of the error in the following insert statement. i used a breakpoint to track the codes while running and i get the exception error  that says (There was an Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Case'). Get you eagles eyes on...

```
public partial class OpenCase : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string adminString;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        adminString = "CA123";
    }

    protected void openCaseBotton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //SQL connection string
        SqlDataSource CSMDataSource = new SqlDataSource();
        CSMDataSource.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CMSSQL3ConnectionString"].ToString();

        //SQL Insert command with variables
        CSMDataSource.InsertCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.Text;
        CSMDataSource.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO Case (CaseID, CaseDesc, DateOpened, CasePriority, AdministratorID) VALUES (@CaseID, @CaseDesc, @DateOpened, @CasePriority, @AdministratorID)";

        //Actual Insertion with values from textboxes into databse fields
        CSMDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("CaseID", caseIDTextBox.Text);
        CSMDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("CaseDesc", caseDescTextBox.Text);
        CSMDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("DateOpened", DateTime.Now.ToString());
        CSMDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("CasePriority", null);
        CSMDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("AdministratorID", adminString.ToString());

        int rowsCommitted = 0;

        //Try catch method to catch exceptions during insert
        try
        {
            rowsCommitted = CSMDataSource.Insert();
            Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('The following errors have occurred:');</script>");
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //error message displayed when exception occurs


            string script = "<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "');</script>";
            Response.Write("The following Error occurred while entering the records into the database" + " " + ex.ToString() + " ");
            Response.Redirect("~/ErrorPage.aspx", false);
        }
        finally
        {
            CSMDataSource = null;
        }

        //Where to go next if insert was successful or failed
        if (rowsCommitted != 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/CaseAdmin.aspx", false);
        }
        else
        {

            Response.Redirect("~/ErrorPage.aspx", false);
        }

    }

    protected void addExhibitBotton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/EntryForms/AddExhibit.aspx", false);

    }
}
```

Seen anything? may be u need a C# error vision goggles...lol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Near the `INSERT` ? well, `CASE` is a SQL reserved word, so try simply:

```
CSMDataSource.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO [Case] (...
```

to tell it that `Case` is an object name, not the SQL keyword.

Comment: @Selase: Also try [CASE] (in upper case). Because DBMS can capitalize objects' names (Oracle does). Use `[Object Name]` in MS SQL Server, `"Object Name"` in Oracle

Comment: @Alexander in SQL Server, the casing can be significant, depending on the database settings. If it is in case-sensitive mode, then `[Case]` will work **if and only if** the table was actually created as `Case` - and `[CASE]` will work **if and only if** the table was created as `CASE`. In case-insensitive mode, either will work fine.

Comment: @Marc: I thought `[]` mean exact match in any situation. So, if you are creating obj in case-insensitive mode, DBMS will capitalize its name and later when using `[]` you have to spell it how it's stored, i.e. upper case. Don't have SQL Server instance at hand. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @Alexander - no, in SQL server the `[]` is optional and merely says "this is an object"; used mainly for keywords or for `[tables with spaces]`, but `select * from foo` and `select * from [foo]` are identical.

Comment: Wish i had seen your comment earlier Marc. guess i scrolled too much and ended up on the answer from paxdiablo that advised 'Case'. am most certain [Case] would have worked having read other answers. Thank you very much for you contribution...its was very very helpful... thanks again

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty certain that `case` is actually an SQL keyword.

Depending on the DBMS, you may have to do something like enclose it in backticks or other delimiters to tell the execution engine to treat it as a non-keyword, something like:

```
CSMDataSource.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO `Case` (CaseID, ...
```

Comment: is it? well i named my database table case so how am i supposed to work around that? At first i had a table named users and it was giving me errors to so i tested the statement in SQL management studio and found out that table previously named Users was a keyword. i went through hell to change the name and all the relationships involved. How many keywords am i supposed to change? Gosh..!!!!

Comment: (1) Find and use the escape delimiters. (2) Rename your table. (3) Well, actually, two was all I could think of (and the first is probably the best bet if you don't want to worry about keyword clashes). I never use keywords for objects myself partially because you should be using more descriptive names and partially because I've seen DB2/z code that looked like `"insert into date(date,seq) select date,seq+1 from date"`.

Comment: @Selase - none at all; please look *carefully* at the two answers provided - which show you how to handle this for different databases.

Comment: @ Marc- I tried the correction from the first answer by placing the case in single quotes like 'Case' and this time around the exception message displays "$exception {"Incorrect syntax near 'Case'."}" so i would have to rename the table then i guess....

Comment: @Selease, for a start, you need to tell us which DBMS you are using. MySQL for example uses _backticks_ (not apostrophes like you have used in the previous comment). I think SQLServer user square brackets. But, to be honest (and, apologetically, brutal), "case" is actually a crappy name for a table. You would be vastly better off with something more descriptive.

Comment: @Selase - no, you do not have to rename it. If this is SQL Server then square brackets are the correct syntax. As I mentioned 27 minutes ago...

Comment: @paxdiablo I disagree; if there is an entity that is logically "a case" (bug-tracking, legal, ... , luggage ;p) then "case" is a perfectly good name.

Comment: @Marc, even for the generic case object, I would still call the table (at a minimum) "cases" rather than "case". It makes `"select * from cases where case_type = 'luggage'"` more readable :-)

Comment: Thanks for all your contibutions. Am actually saving data regarding crime cases which is why i chose case to represent that table. since earlier answers recommend i change the table or enclose the case word in brackets with the later not helpful, i changed the table name and it works now. but i wish i hadn't since its caused so many confusions about how i had mapped the database in my mind.but i guess the harm is already done and id just put up with it but should i encounter any further SQL Server Key words, i know exactly what to do now rather than rename the table.Once again am very grateful

Comment: @selase, check for keywords at the time you create the tables. That willsave you from having to change a lot of code if you decide not to use it later. It is best to avoid keywords altogether. Or search Books Online for the keyword list using this search criteria: keywords [SQL Server], reserved

Comment: Thanks HLGEM...id definitely take a good look at that keyword list and keep them in mind....am certain i will not fall into the keyword trap again...Thanks to all your intuitive advise....its really an honour to have all of you comment here...thanks so much